# geopandas.explore - How to plot more than one layer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I have one dataset with polygons geometry and another with points, I want to plot both in the same graphic with geopandas.explore function but I get the error ***'Map' object has no attribute 'set_aspect'***

The code is:

````
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax= plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,5)) 

Polygons= df.explore('column', scheme='Quantiles', cmap= 'GnBu', k=6)

points= df_points.plot(ax= Polygons)

plt.show()```
````

Comment: You are mixing oil with water … folium and matplotlib . 2x explore{} passing second call return of first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- have used built in sample geometry to create MWE
- your core issue is that you are mixing **folium** and **matplotlib**.  These are two completely independent libraries
- simple case of taking **folium** map returned from plotting polygons and then plotting another layer on this map by passing it to `explore()` call for points

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).loc[lambda d: d["continent"].eq("Africa")]
df_points = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"), mask=df)

m = df.explore(height=250, width=500, name="Polygons")
m = df_points.explore(m=m, color="red", name="Points")
# this is completely optional
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]